# How maven-compiler-plugin work with different jdk?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T03:58:13-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-98-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Only jvm version installed on the machine.

---

In `pom.xml`, on setting `source` & `target` version as `1.4`,

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.4</source>
          <target>1.4</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

---

Here is the output of `mvn package`,

```
$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mywebapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.2.pom (2.4 kB at 934 B/s)
....
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mywebapp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/mohet01/git/Projects/myapp/mywebapp/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ mywebapp ---
...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-api-1.5.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-api-1.5.3.pom (624 B at 700 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-1.5.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-1.5.3.pom (1.5 kB at 1.8 kB/s)
...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-manager-1.5.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-manager-1.5.3.pom (634 B at 732 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-javac-1.5.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-javac-1.5.3.pom (797 B at 871 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.5.3/plexus-compilers-1.5.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.5.3/plexus-compilers-1.5.3.pom (7.6 kB at 9.4 kB/s)
...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-api-1.5.3.jar
...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-manager-1.5.3.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-api-1.5.3.jar (20 kB at 20 kB/s)
...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-javac-1.5.3.jar
...
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-javac-1.5.3.jar (14 kB at 8.2 kB/s)
...

Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-manager-1.5.3.jar (5.3 kB at 2.1 kB/s)
.....

[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [mywebapp] in [/home/mohet01/git/Projects/myapp/mywebapp/target/mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/mohet01/git/Projects/myapp/mywebapp/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [79 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/mohet01/git/Projects/myapp/mywebapp/target/mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.643 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-07T01:56:43-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/140M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
$
```

---

Does maven pull 1.4 version of `javac` compiler from online maven repo before compiling java source code? How to point to corresponding jdk?

Comment: No - it just uses the `-source` and `-target` options of [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). Maven is not going to download a specific version of the Java compiler or JDK.

Comment: JDK has to be installed on the appropriate system. BTW: Is there reason why are you using such an ancient version of maven-compiler-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need jsp and servlet jars only. How should maven point to jdk 1.4?

Comment: If you really need to compile with JDK 1.4 you have to use [Toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) otherwise you can't use Maven 3.5.X (cause it needs at minimum JDK 1.7)..

Comment: @khmarbaise let me try

Answer (score 1):

No, `javac` has the ability to compile to backward compalibile code (with slight exceptions)